# Timer in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, timer, foreach

I have a foreach loop which will go through every string in an array, I want to make a timer which ticks every 100 miliseconds and when it ticks it goes to the other string in the array, so for example:

Ticks 100 miliseconds
thepath = Assets/Star/Star_00001.png
Ticks 100 miliseconds
thepath = Assets/Star/Star_00002.png

So far I have this:

```
private void Button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] images = new string[] { "Star_00001.png", "Star_00002.png", "Star_00003.png", "Star_00004.png", "Star_00005.png", "Star_00006.png", "Star_00007.png";
        string path = "Assets/Star/";

            foreach(string file in images)
            {
              string thepath = Path.Combine(path,file);
              asset.Text = thepath;
            }
    }
```

How should I approach and do this? (Sorry if you dont understand, i found it hard to explain myself, if you have further questions just comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate a timer using [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You'll need to mark your method `async` so you may `await` inside it:

```
private async void Button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       string[] images = new string[] { "Star_00001.png", "Star_00002.png", "Star_00003.png", "Star_00004.png", "Star_00005.png", "Star_00006.png", "Star_00007.png";

       string path = "Assets/Star/";
       foreach(string file in images)
       {
            string thepath = Path.Combine(path,file);
            asset.Text = thepath;
            await Task.Delay(100);
       }
}
```